# Programmatically downloading files pushed through a PHP page

Tags: java, download, redirect

Some PHP sites use a page to act as a middle man for handling file downloads.

With a browser this works transparently. There seems to a be a slight pause while the php page processes the request.

However, attempting a download through Java using a `URL` or `HttpURLConnection` returns a plain html page. How could I get the file downloads working in the same way?

Edit: Here is an example link:

http://depot.eice.be/index.php?annee_g=jour&cours=poo

Edit: Here is some of the code I've been testing:

```
// This returns an HTML page

private void downloadURL(String theURL) {
    URL url;
    InputStream is = null;
    DataInputStream dis;
    String s;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        url = new URL(theURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.connect();

        if (conn.getResponseCode()!=HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            return;


        InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int i;
        while ((i = in.read()) != -1) {
            bos.write(i);
        }

        byte[] b = bos.toByteArray();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( getNameFromUrl( theURL ) );
        fos.write(b);
        fos.close();
        conn.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

```
// This will throw Exceptions if the URL isn't in the expected format

public String getNameFromUrl(String url) {

    int slashIndex = url.lastIndexOf('/');
    int dotIndex = url.lastIndexOf('.');

    System.out.println("url:" + url + "," + slashIndex + "," + dotIndex);

    if (dotIndex == -1) {
        return url.substring(slashIndex + 1);
    } else {
        try {
            return url.substring(slashIndex + 1, url.length());
        } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            return "";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not enough information. Does the page requires some authentication? Does it use cookies? Did you try to follow redirects?

Comment: Do you mean something like the Download Link of the Project of the Month at `Sourceforge.net`. In the Case of Sourceforge the Download Buttons on the Start page  use the the title attribute `<a href='project/download' title='project.iso'> ...` Which is displayed as 'project.iso' when you move the mouse over the button but it's acutally a link to a html page. In this case you can simply follow the link and search for the right link on the download page. The Download page itself contains a `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; correctDownloadLink">` which redirects the browser to the download.

Comment: @EugeneRetunsky No authentication, no cookies. Links are public with a php page (ex: download.php?f=...) that is acting as the middle man. What I want to know is how to reproduce the behaviour of a browser when it encounters such a a link.

Comment: @andih As described above a php page is referred in the url, probably to hide the real location of files, and is being used to push them to a browser when a click takes place. I've posted a link with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution using HttpUnit. The source of the framework is available if you wish to see how this is handled.

```
public void downloadURL(String url) throws IOException {

    WebConversation wc = new WebConversation();
    WebResponse indexResp = wc.getResource(new GetMethodWebRequest(url));
    WebLink[] links = new WebLink[1];
    try {
        links = indexResp.getLinks();
    } catch (SAXException ex) {
        // Log
    }

    for (WebLink link : links) {
        try {
            link.click();
        } catch (SAXException ex) {
            // Log
        }
        WebResponse resp = wc.getCurrentPage();
        String fileName = resp.getURL().getFile();
        fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        System.out.println("filename:" + fileName);
        File file = new File(fileName);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
                resp.getInputStream());
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(file.getName()));
        int i;
        while ((i = bis.read()) != -1) {
            bos.write(i);
        }
        bis.close();
        bos.close();
    }
    System.out.println("Done downloading.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering no other constrains, you can read the redirected URL from the HTTP header and connect to that URL directly from JAVA.

Answer (score 2):

There is an API setting to follow redirects automatically – but it should be true by default. How do you access the URL?

See [Java API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFollowRedirects%28boolean%29)...

Comment: I've posted some code above for you. I will see if using one of those methods makes a difference. I have the impression that what is happening with the browser is that it does a short pause while the PHP page is busy whereas the Java application starts the download straight away.

Comment: Any HTTP request will have it's own timeout... the connection is requested... made... handled. If the server responds in time the redirected URL should be handled accordingly.

Comment: I see. Maybe something is happening on the PHP side that is causing a difference. See the answer added for some working code. This will get the files or pages as expected from the example url above.